# django admin why my ForeignKey do'nt display?

Tags: django, admin, foreign-key-relationship, selected, display

In django admin page, it have default value on IDC filed,But in edit page,it not display. what method can resulove it?
[one image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWXeL.png)

rt
[two image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXDUN.png)

code

```
class IDC(models.Model):
      uuid = UUIDField(auto=True, primary_key=True)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=64,verbose_name=u'机房名称')

class Server(models.Model):
      idc = models.ForeignKey(IDC, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u'机房', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class ServerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      model = models.Server
      exclude = ('memo',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you do not set default value for `idc` field in `Server` model, this will not be shown in the admin when you create a new object. It will only be shown if you edit already existing object. In order to have default value for this field in the admin, set default value for your `idc` field in the `Server` model.

Comment: I express wrong,it not default value, it had object. but this don't shown.

Comment: I found when set uuid is primary_key will appear this situation,but use django default primary_key "id" is ok. why?

Comment: when i change "uuid" filed to "id",it does OK

Comment: id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False),I think is django1.9 features

Comment: I do not really understand what your problem is. Please, try to describe the problem more specific so that we can help you.